# NullPointerException in Titan on every property on every vertex

Tags: titan

Graph created with Titan 0.4.4, we're getting a NPE on line 262 of `com.thinkaurelias.titan.graphdb.database.EdgeSerializer` (see below for offending line).

```
private static boolean hasGenericDataType(TitanKey key) {
    return key.getDataType().equals(Object.class);
}
```

I'm not sure how, but none of the keys on any of the properties on any of our vertices have a datatype set. Is there something I can do to fix this? When retrieving any property on any vertex, I'm getting this null pointer.

Comment: Error arose due to a Kryo dependency conflict: https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/635

Comment: Thanks! Should I close this, or answer it?